# Hidden Markov model classifying a sequence in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, machine-learning, classification, hidden-markov-models

I'm very new to machine learning, I'v read about Matlab's Statistics toolbox for hidden Markov model, I want to classify a given sequence of signals using it. I'v 3D co-ordinates in matrix `P` i.e [501x3] and I want to train model based on that. Evert complete trajectory ends on a specfic set of points, i.e at (0,0,0) where it achieves its target.

What is the appropriate Pseudocode/approach according to my scenario.

My Pseudocode:

1. 501x3 matrix `P` is Emission matrix where each co-ordinate is state
2. random NxN transition matrix values (but i'm confused in it)
3. generating test sequence using the function `hmmgenerate`
4. train using `hmmtrain(sequence,old_transition,old_emission)`
5. give final transition and emission matrix to `hmmdecode` with an unknown sequence to give the probability (confusing also)

**EDIT 1:**
In a nutshell, I want to classify 10 classes of trajectories having each of `[501x3]` with HMM. I want to sampled 50 rows i.e `[50x3]` for each trajectory in order to build model. However, I'v `murphyk's` toolbox of HMM for such random sequences.

Comment: I dont follow, what are the hidden states of your model, and what are the observations? what are you trying to classify, and how many classes do you have? Recall that HMMs work with a discrete set of states with either discrete or continuous observations (the Statistics Toolbox only implement the former). If your states are in the continuous domain (e.g tracking trajectories), then you need to look into Kalman filters instead... Please provide more details

Comment: What exactly are you asking? Please differentiate more clearly between the question, and the additional information. Also make sure it is one clear question, rather than a few things you are unsure about.

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin Please see EDIT 1, I think I'v cleard my problem. I want to build a model of HMM that can generate 50 sampled matrix of trajectory and trained on that. I want this as to classification of trajectories using HMM.

Comment: @AhsanAli: This is still not clear to me..

Comment: @Amro OK, What U want to know more about it, I havn't idea about that, please ask.

Comment: @AhsanAli: What are you inputs, and what is the desired output? And exactly how does your problem fit the HMM framework? What are the known parameters and what do you want to estimate (transition matrices, emission distribution functions)? How many hidden states are in the model, and what do they represent? It is unclear what you are asking, you need to exactly define the problem and provide enough details...

Comment: @Amro OK, I have 10 classes of trajectories having 5 in each, initially a trajectory is `[501x3]` but I sampled the input to `[50x3]` as in INPUT, the desired output is to classify those trajectories and calculate `vetrabi` for them. the known parameters are the states that are 50, and random sequences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement/case tells to build and train a hidden Markov's model having following components specially using `murphyk's` toolbox for HMM as per the choice:

1. O = Observation's vector
2. Q = States vector
3. T = vectors sequence
4. nex = number of sequences
5. M = number of mixtures

**Demo Code (from `murphyk's` toolbox):**

```
    O = 8;          %Number of coefficients in a vector
    T = 420;         %Number of vectors in a sequence
    nex = 1;        %Number of sequences
    M = 1;          %Number of mixtures
    Q = 6;          %Number of states



data = randn(O,T,nex);

% initial guess of parameters
prior0 = normalise(rand(Q,1));
transmat0 = mk_stochastic(rand(Q,Q));

if 0
    Sigma0 = repmat(eye(O), [1 1 Q M]);
    % Initialize each mean to a random data point
    indices = randperm(T*nex);
    mu0 = reshape(data(:,indices(1:(Q*M))), [O Q M]);
    mixmat0 = mk_stochastic(rand(Q,M));
else
    [mu0, Sigma0] = mixgauss_init(Q*M, data, 'full');
    mu0 = reshape(mu0, [O Q M]);
    Sigma0 = reshape(Sigma0, [O O Q M]);
    mixmat0 = mk_stochastic(rand(Q,M));
end

[LL, prior1, transmat1, mu1, Sigma1, mixmat1] = ...
    mhmm_em(data, prior0, transmat0, mu0, Sigma0, mixmat0, 'max_iter', 5);


loglik = mhmm_logprob(data, prior1, transmat1, mu1, Sigma1, mixmat1);
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a general outline of the approach to classifying d-dimensional sequences using hidden Markov models:

#### 1) Training:

For each class `k`:

- prepare an HMM model. This includes initializing the following:

  - a transition matrix: Q-by-Q matrix, where Q is the number of states
  - a vector of prior probabilities: Q-by-1 vector
  - the emission model: in your case the observations are 3D points so you could use a [mutlivariate normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution) (with specified mean vector and covariance matrix) or a [Guassian mixture model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixture_model) (a bunch of MVN distributions combined using mixture coefficient)
- after properly initializing the above parameters, you train the HMM model, feeding it the set of sequences belong to this class (EM algorithm).

#### 2) Prediction

Next to classify a new sequence `X`:

- you compute the log-likelihood of the sequence using each model `log P(X|model_k)`
- then you pick the class that gave the highest probability. This is the class prediction.

---

As I mentioned in the comments, the [Statistics Toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/hidden-markov-models-hmm.html) only implement discrete observation HMM models, so you will have to find another libraries or implement the code yourself. Kevin Murphy's toolboxes ([HMM toolbox](http://www.cs.ubc.ca/~murphyk/Software/HMM/hmm.html), [BNT](https://code.google.com/p/bnt/), [PMTK3](https://github.com/probml/pmtk3)) are popular choices in this domain.

Here are some answers I posted in the past using Kevin Murphy's toolboxes:

- [Issue in training hidden markov model and usage for classification](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9754906/97160)
- [Simple example/use-case for a BNT gaussian_CPD](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11004748/97160)

The above answers are somewhat different from what you are trying to do here, but it's a good place to start.

Comment: I'v viewed this  so many times `Issue in training hidden markov model and usage for classification`, but unable to clarify my matrices, I think my states are the random sampled 50 points, what are the sequences etc. Is it possible U provide some code releated to my problem using Murphy's toolbox?